# Init class instances with a constant set of properties which is initialized once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have some instances of a class, `MyClass`, which share some constant properties read from file, but also have properties with values unique to the instance. However, I want to read file only once for all instances.

Something like

**config.json**

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
}
```

Then classes definition:

```
class MyBaseClass:

    def __new__(cls):
        with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
            for key, value in json.load(f).items():
                setattr(cls, key, value)

class MyClass(MyBaseClass):

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.c = param
```

And when I initialize instances of `MyClass`, I want

```
inst1 = MyClass("One")
inst2 = MyClass("Two")
```

to have `inst1.c` is `One` and `inst2.c` is `Two`. But I want to achieve that in a way so that MyBaseClass reads data from `config.json` only once. Like in a singleton. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `MyBaseClass` to be a metaclass, so this is done just once.

```
>>> class MyBaseClass(type):
...    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
...        x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
...        print('In metaclass')
...        with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
...            for key, value in json.load(f).items():
...                setattr(x, key, value)
...        return  x
...
>>>
```

And now, specify `MyBaseClass` as a metaclass of `MyClass`.

```
>>> class MyClass(metaclass=MyBaseClass):    
...    def __init__(self, param):
...        self.c = param
...
In metaclass
>>>
```

When `MyClass` is defined, that invokes `MyBaseClass.__new__` method just once. Now,

```
>>> inst1 = MyClass("One")
>>> inst2 = MyClass("Two")
```

Will result in the two instances being created without any further reads for `config.json`.

Comment: I thought it might be smth. related to metaclasses, but was not familiar with them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the framework already there. There are a number of pieces of code that run when a class is first created. The simplest one to use is the class body itself. You could use it to create a class variable containing the attributes you wanted with a snippet like the one you show here:

```
class MyBaseClass:
    with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
        attributes = json.load(f)

    def __new__(cls):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.__dict__.update(cls.attributes)
```

*Any* name in the class namespace that remains after the class is run becomes a class variable, not just methods. Updating a dictionary will only work if you have a regular class that doesn't use slots or have conflicting properties. In those cases, use your `setattr` loop in `__new__`.